# Salesforce Sharing - Add button not showing to system admin for records owned by communities users

Tags: sharing

Im a system admin user, I have a custom object with sharing set to "private".  As a system admin i see a sharing button on the object record, but when i view the sharing details page i dont see "add" as an option?

This is even though my system admin user has "modify all" permissions, and if i hit "expand list" i see my user showing with "Full Access"??

What am i missing here?

UPDATE: Also wanted to note that this object doesnt have a master object, so thats not the problem either  see the last screen shot... the object in question is "Customer"

UPDATE 2: If i change the owner of the object to the system admin the add button shows up and works fine.  But why would that be, shouldnt system admin be able to do it without being the owner?

Update 3: the records in question are owned by communities users which seems to be where the issue is but not sure of what the solution is?

see screen shots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What type of user is the Owner when you don't see the button? I have seen this kind of behavior with Customer Portal users owning things.

Comment: Yea they are owned by commmunities users.. is that the problem?  any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: Hey Jeremy, we're you ever able to find away around the issues with portal users owning the content?

Comment: My workaround was a trigger that assigned a different owner to the custom object record. I never talked to Salesforce about this issue, since my workaround fit with the particular environment.

Answer (score 1):

If the object has a master-detail relationship with a parent object, sharing is controlled by that object regardless of permissions.

If your intention is to have sharing decoupled from the parent, then you would need to change that relationship from master-detail to lookup.

Here is a good help article explaining about master-detail relationships and the implications of different relationship types:

[Considerations for Relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Would the "Sharing" Button still be present on a Detail record of the M/D, though?

Comment: No, and that's what his answer is saying.

Comment: @sfdcfox - The question states that there is a sharing button on the record, so it isn't a Detail in an M/D.

Comment: yea this isnt the issue, its not a detail object, there is no master object, something else is wrong

Comment: Oops. Looks like I'll have to dig into that further. I remember from my days of support that there are other reasons why "sharing" would disappear, but I can't recall for the life of me what they would be.

Comment: I notice that you have External Organization-Wide Defaults enabled, have you checked with Support that it won't affect your ability to add manual sharing?

Comment: I think it was on by default, and im not sure its something i can turn off

Comment: Serves me right for not looking closely at the screenshots, I see now that you don't have a M-D relationship anywhere on your object.